# Filename search using Shell Script

Tags: shell

I am trying to search for set of files with the same name between 2 directories

```
**dir1** (/MyFolder/sample/test1)                     
file1.txt                   
file2.txt                   
file3.txt
file4.txt

**dir2** (/MyFolder/sample/test2)
file1.txt
file4.txt
```

I am using the *diff* command in the following way

```
diff -sr /MyFolder/sample/test1/ /MyFolder/sample/test2/ | awk -F: '{print $1}' | grep -r ".txt"
```

The result is as follows:

```
Files /MyFolder/sample/test1/file1.txt and /MyFolder/sample/test2/file1.txt are identical
Files /MyFolder/sample/test1/file4.txt and /MyFolder/sample/test2/file4.txt are identical
```

The result that I am looking for is just the file name:

```
file1.txt
file4.txt
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: `diff` is for comparing the _contents_ of files, not the _names_ of files.

Answer (score 3):

A little fiddling with ls & grep should work too:

```
ls dir1 | grep "`ls dir2`"
```

Or, If it's a C Shell:

```
ls dir1 | grep -E "`ls dir2 | tr '\n' '|'` "
```

As observed by **radical7**, the first method wouldn't work in a C shell, as the newlines get lost while passing to grep. For such cases we could use a regex, instead.

`grep -E` or simply `egrep` allows us to use a regex of the form `file1.txt|file2.txt` as pattern.

Also, do note that the whitespace at the end is intentional.

Comment: Very cool!  Curiously, that form doesn't work in c-shell based shells.  The string interpolation in sh-based shells preserves (or inserts - can't quite tell) the newline, while newlines in the interpolated string are removed in c-shell (if they were ever there in the first place).

Comment: Interesting. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (hopefully) simple, easy to understand method using some local files:

```
cd /MyFolder/sample
( cd test1 ; ls -1 * ) > test1-files
( cd test2 ; ls -1 * ) > test2-files
comm -12 test1-files test2-files
```

The `comm` command will take two sorted files (which `ls` does in this case for us, otherwise you'd need to `sort`), and outputs three columns: lines exclusively in the first file, lines exclusively in the second file, and matching lines in both files.  To limit the output to what you asked for, the `-12` on the `comm` command suppresses the first two columns.

However, if you want all this done without temporary files, you can use this sequence of pipes:

```
(cd test1 ; ls -1 ; cd ../test2 ; ls -1) | sort | uniq -c | grep -v "1 " | awk '{ print $2; }'
```

If you're unfamiliar with the commands-in-parenthesis construct, it executes the files in a subshell, aggregating the output into stdin to be passed along the pipe chain.

In fact, you can nest the commands:

```
((cd test1 ; ls -1) ; (cd test2 ; ls -1)) | ...
```

Note here there isn't the `cd ../test2` that there was in the original example.  When the subshell exits, you're returned to the directory that you started from.